Sending files within form-data with fetch API
I've been trying to connect my React frontend with my express and MongoDB backend. I used Postman to test my requests and it was great until I tried it with fetch and Axios.
Here is the working postman request:

Here is my express middleware to handle file uploads for this route:
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const userId = req.body.owner;
    const fieldName = file.fieldname;
    let uploadPath = "";
    if (fieldName === "photo")
      uploadPath = path.join("dev-data/images/beat-images", userId);
    if (fieldName === "fullTrack")
      uploadPath = path.join("dev-data/tracks", userId);

    fs.promises
      .access(uploadPath, fs.constants.F_OK)
      .then(() => cb(null, uploadPath))
      .catch(() => {
        fs.promises
          .mkdir(uploadPath, { recursive: true })
          .then(() => cb(null, uploadPath))
          .catch((err) => cb(err, null));
      });
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const originalName = file.originalname;
    const sluggifiedName = slugify(originalName, { lower: true });
    const ext = path.extname(originalName);
    const fileName = `${path.basename(
      sluggifiedName,
      ext
    )}-${Date.now()}${ext}`;
    cb(null, fileName);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = upload.fields([
  { name: "photo", maxCount: 1 },
  { name: "fullTrack", maxCount: 1 },
]);

Actual error is happenning on the path.join() function. It throws a parameter error. Like it can't get the file properly.
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Here is the code that I tried to send a POST request with form-data:
      if (allFieldsValid) {
        console.log("All fields are valid");
        const formData = new FormData();

        for (const key in dataState) {
          formData.append(key, dataState[key]);
        }

        // Authentication is not implemented yet
        formData.append("owner", "6604178ac93ccb58387d3ba4");

        const res = await fetch(`${serverURLs.BEATS}`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        });

        console.log(res);
      } else {
        console.log("Some fields are invalid");
     }

Here is the "formData" with the appended values:

Which lacks the description field which is not required for the mongoose model. I mean it works without it too in postman.
I also tried it with Axios too:
      const res = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${serverURLs.BEATS}`,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

Bu the result was the same.

So what is the contents of req.body at the point where you try access req.body.owner?
Is it just missing .owner, or is the whole body wrong?

You might be logging your FormData but can you confirm that this is actually the value of your FormData? Also can you share dataState?

In Postman, you send the files after the owner field (the two file fields are placed under the owner field).
However, in your code, you send the files before the owner field (you append it after all the other fields are appended).
According to multer's docs:

Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends
on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

That is why your request works in Postman, but your frontend code doesn't:
the owner field is not populated yet when destination is called, so req.body.owner is undefined.

It worked like a charm. I thought it was getting the data as a whole. Thanks, man.
